# WhereIn laravel возвращает только один элемент

Tags: laravel

Имеется следующий код

```
$relations = PR::where('status','1')
            ->whereIn('id',array($PR['related']))
            ->get();
```

Дело в том что запрос возвращает только 1 элемент, если вставить такой запрос то выведет все 3 элемента

```
$relations = PR::where('status','1')
            ->whereIn('id',array(1,2,3))
            ->get();
```

Почему происходит так? учитывая что $PR['related'] равно 1,2,3

Answer (score 2):

```
->whereIn('id',explode(',', $PR['related']))
```

`array($PR['related'])` - это `array('1,2,3')`, что, согласитесь, далеко не то же самое, что и `array(1, 2, 3)`.